# Xcode - No known class method for selector from a class

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors

I'm using a third party class `ActionSheetPicker` in my app. One of the class of it, `ActionSheetStringPicker` I'm using at two places in my app. Though I imported it in `.pch` file. Now in one view controller its working and not working in other view controller. Any idea what is the issue for this error? I know its hard to answer this as I'm the only person who've source code of my project. But any help would be helpful.

This is the peace of code showing error,

```
[ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"hello" rows:@[@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E"] initialSelection:0 doneBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker, NSInteger selectedIndex, id selectedValue) {

} cancelBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker) {

} origin:self.view];
```

[image]

Comment: Can you check if your code has some macro named **rows**. Probably that is causing the issue. If you do have it try renaming it to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check if your code has some macro named **rows**. Probably that is causing the issue. If you do have it try renaming it to something else.

Comment: Again, thank you so much @Vivek, you saved my life and made my day! Cheers to you buddy! :) :) :)